# Creating many different StationaryMovement nodes quickly

Tags: one-simulator

I'm trying to create many stationary nodes with different locations (to act as bus stop nodes). At the minute, I'm creating many groups containing just one node with different locations.

```
Group6.groupID = Bus_stop
Group6.nrofHosts = 1
Group6.movementModel = StationaryMovement
Group6.nodeLocation = 1936,1386

Group7.groupID = Bus_stop
Group7.nrofHosts = 1
Group7.movementModel = StationaryMovement
Group7.nodeLocation = 3055,945
```

Is there a quicker way than copying the same few lines and changing the node location every time?

StationaryMovement only accepts one pair of coordinates, and wont dynamically create nodes from an array.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are options like [GridLocation](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/master/src/movement/GridLocation.java) but for your purpose probably easiest is to extend the StationaryMovement module (i.e., to make new module) to accept array of locations.